# How to retrieve data from different DatabaseReference at same time

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have places in different cities in my real time database (firebase).

Following is my database structure.

[image: Database Structure]

But according to firebase tutorial, I tried following code to get data

```
cityA.queryOrdered(byChild: "completed").observe(.value, with: { snapShot in
            var newItems: [AttractionPlace] = []
            for child in snapShot.children {
                if let snapShot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                    let attraction = AttractionPlace(snapShot: snapShot) {
                        newItems.append(attraction)
                }
            }
            print(newItems.count)
        })
```

I also would like to get data from cityB at the SAME TIME and no idea how to retrieve. I know I can repeat same action to `cityB`. But is there any better way?

Comment: Just repeat what you did for cityA.  There is no way to optimize multiple queries.

Comment: Yes but can combine to one query since they all under `attractions` object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how you want your data structured. Can you show me what an `AttractionPlace` is supposed to look like? The code below does what you want appending the name of each place to `newItems`, but without specifying from which city it is. Take notice that I did not use your `AttractionPlace` object.

```
let dataref = Database.database().reference()
dataref.child("attractions").observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in
    var newItems = [AnyObject]()
    for city in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot] {
        let value = city.value as? NSDictionary ?? [:]
        for child in value {
            let attraction = child.value
            newItems.append(attraction as AnyObject)
        }
    }
    print("newItems: ",newItems)
    print("newItems.count: ",newItems.count)
})
```

Result:

```
newItems:  [Place 3, Place 4, Place 1, Place 2]
newItems.count:  4
```

Comment: After I set  self.dataRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "attractions") and remove `.child("attractions")`, and then it is working. Thanks a lot!